# If $g(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$, and $f\circ g(x) = x^2$, find $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

$$g(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$$

$$f\circ g(x) = x^2$$

$$f(x) =\text{ ?}$$

Hello, I don't have any clue how to solve that. Do you have any ideas how to solve that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give you a hint:
Write $f \circ g(x) =f \circ \dfrac{x}{1+x}=f\big(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\big)=x^2 $

Then plug $t=\dfrac{x}{1+x}$ and solve for $x$.

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I tried to do that, but I couldn't reach a solution..

Answer (score 2):

**HINTS:**

First find the inverse function for $g$, so

$$g^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{u+1}\right)=u$$

Then

$$(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))=x^2$$
so
$$f\left(g\left(g^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{u+1}\right)\right)\right)=\left(g^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{u+1}\right)\right)^2$$

You should be able to continue from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question is based on the fact that we still do not know how to inverse a function. Do you have another solution?

Comment: This shows why we want questioners to give context to their questions. If you haven't covered how to find the inverse of a function, Ranc's answer is better for you than mine. The first step to solving $t=\frac{x}{1+x}$ for $x$ is to multiply both sides by $1+x$, then gather the terms that include $x$ and factor out the $x$. The rest should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It is given:

$$f(\frac{x}{x+1})=x^2$$

If we let:

$$u=\frac{x}{x+1}$$

Then,

$$x=\frac{u}{1-u}$$

Thus,

$$f(u)=(\frac{u}{1-u})^2$$

Which implies ....